# Should I run mysql_upgrade after minor version upgrade via RPM?

Tags: mysql, upgrade

I'm running `yum update` to update my server from time to time.

When I see that `mysql-community-server` is being upgraded from say, `5.6.27` to `5.6.28`, should I run `mysql_upgrade`, or is it only when upgrading from say `5.6` to `5.7`?

Also, do the RPMs provided by [MySQL.com's YUM repositories](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/yum/) automatically run `mysql_upgrade`, so do I need to care at all?

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, yes.

See [A Quick Guide to Using the MySQL Yum Repository](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-yum-repo-quick-guide/en/)

> Once the server restarts, run mysql_upgrade to check and possibly
>   resolve any incompatibilities between the old data and the upgraded
>   software.

Comment: The paragraph you quote immediately follows the one *selecting a target series*, which makes me doubtful about whether `mysql_upgrade` applies to minor version updates. But I think you're right.